# docker build image access denied

Tags: linux, docker

### i have build one image on local and docker repository using this command

```
    $ docker build -t image:local test/. 
               or 
    $ docker build -t <dockerusername>/<filename>:tagname test/.
```

### *output:*

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/5 : FROM ubuntu/latest
pull access denied for ubuntu/latest, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

- using linux operating system
- i did had **$ dockerlogin**
- and docker **$ docker logout**

can you help me !

Comment: Do you mean `FROM ubuntu:latest`, with a colon and not a slash?  The syntax you have here is looking for a repository named `latest` in Docker Hub owned by `ubuntu`; you want the `latest` tag of a repository named `ubuntu`.

Answer (score -1):

The following script will be enough in your use case:

FROM something.com/..../lrh7:latest

```
RUN whoami
RUN groupadd -g 1000 AB_DOCKER_SETUP_GROUP
OR, if you still DO want to specify the same default shell:
```

FROM something.com/..../lrh7:latest

```
RUN whoami
SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
RUN groupadd -g 1000 AB_DOCKER_SETUP_GROUP
```

Comment: # This error is credentials i fixed it
 -> follow this link:
       https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store.